# Why did IntelliJ IDEA crash?

Tags: intellij-idea

My IntelliJ IDEA's Version is  `15.0.6 (IU-143.2370.31)`

It always crashes when I use it.
Here is the snippet of the problem report

```
Process:               idea [7902]
Path:                  /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 15.app/Contents/MacOS/idea
Identifier:            com.jetbrains.intellij
Version:               15.0.6 (IU-143.2370.31)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           idea [7902]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2016-07-18 19:11:13.744 +0800
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.11.5 (15F34)
Report Version:        11
Anonymous UUID:        F89C4D90-6E24-6839-A0EC-646466E39AF6

Sleep/Wake UUID:       483379D4-51BE-4BC7-9DAA-912784CD219D

Time Awake Since Boot: 68000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       37000 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        18  Java: Java2D Queue Flusher

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       EXC_I386_GPFLT
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Application Specific Information:
abort() called

Thread 0:: AppKit Thread  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff9ab45f72 mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff9ab453b3 mach_msg + 55
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8b8e51c4 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 212
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8b8e468c __CFRunLoopRun + 1356
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8b8e3ed8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 296
5   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff9befc935 RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 235
6   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff9befc76f ReceiveNextEventCommon + 432
7   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff9befc5af _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 71
8   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8bd1adf6 _DPSNextEvent + 1067
9   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8bd1a226 -[NSApplication _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 454
10  libosxapp.dylib                 0x000000012c0c54e3 -[NSApplicationAWT nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 124
11  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8bd0ed80 -[NSApplication run] + 682
12  libosxapp.dylib                 0x000000012c0c5346 +[NSApplicationAWT runAWTLoopWithApp:] + 156
13  liblwawt.dylib                  0x000000012cac617d -[AWTStarter starter:] + 873
14  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff9cf15fde __NSThreadPerformPerform + 279
15  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8b905881 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
16  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8b8e4fbc __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
17  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8b8e44df __CFRunLoopRun + 927
18  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8b8e3ed8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 296
19  com.jetbrains.intellij          0x00000001000013bf main + 357
20  com.jetbrains.intellij          0x0000000100001238 start + 52

Thread 1:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff9ab4cefa kevent_qos + 10
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff97b8a165 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 216
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff97b89dcd _dispatch_mgr_thread + 52

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff9ab4bdb6 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8afaa728 _pthread_cond_wait + 767
2   libjvm.dylib                    0x0000000104d2f85f os::PlatformEvent::park() + 173
3   libjvm.dylib                    0x0000000104d0f97a ParkCommon(ParkEvent*, long long) + 42
4   libjvm.dylib                    0x0000000104d1016c Monitor::IWait(Thread*, long long) + 160
5   libjvm.dylib                    0x0000000104d10348 Monitor::wait(bool, long, bool) + 246
6   libjvm.dylib                    0x0000000104e0943c Threads::destroy_vm() + 80
7   libjvm.dylib                    0x0000000104c20cdd jni_DestroyJavaVM + 223
8   com.jetbrains.intellij          0x0000000100003837 -[Launcher launch] + 851
9   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff9ced4e64 __NSThread__start__ + 1351
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8afa999d _pthread_body + 131
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8afa991a _pthread_start + 168
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8afa7351 thread_start + 13
```

I don't know why is this, who can explain it for me?

Comment: It's always a good idea to specify a reproduction script when reporting a problem or asking for help. The summary *"It always crashes when I use it"* is not really informative.

Comment: @bahrep I bet he's just executing the included startup script.

Comment: @m0skit0 I do not execute any script, just coding.

Comment: @MartinDai IntelliJ starts with a script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a bug in IDEA, see the issue [IDEA-146955](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-146955).

Comment: it's really a bug, but Jetbrains still not fix it, i don't wanna get the crashes again, so sad.

Comment: @MartinDai it seems that you are using outdated IDEA version. Upgrade it. And don't forget to report the problem or vote up on the existing bug tracker entry.

Comment: It's 2020 now, and the bug has not been fixed yet